# How to handle a project manager who is not getting satisfied with his own design/plan?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, project-management

I am working in a start-up where we have a team that consists of 2 developers, 2 testers, and 1 tech lead, that's me. Database design, UI design, and the workflow are decided and managed by our project manager. Additionally, we have two managing directors,  but they don't interfere in the technical perspectives. Our project manager is managing the projects as well as he is one of the directors of the company. He is holding some shares too.

I am the tech lead, and we are all working in a very big project which has more than 50 Forms and 100 reports. We are a start up, I participate in developing too. As a Tech. Lead, basically I have to work on some tougher parts of the project. And sometimes I have to review the others code too.

Our problem is that our project manager is not getting satisfied easily with his project design.

He is feeling unsatisfied about his new update after being made by us. Meaning he needs more, not meant that he is unsatisfied with our performance. I guess that he is not making a satisfactory plan before initiating an update in our bigger project.

Whenever I get a chance to speak with him, I tried to explain the danger. But he is simply saying "I am also an ordinary human being. My plans may go wrong sometimes. In order to point/correct mistakes we have appointed you as a Tech. Lead." See, how could I do the assigned tasks with high perfection if I try to point out that mistakes in control flow of the entire project daily?

Is this a common behavior with all PMs? If not then tell me how to handle when he is making this kind of continuous unplanned updates?

For Example:

1. In the middle of the development, or even after completing the testing, he is insisting that we change the entire UI/Workflow.
2. Adding/removing database fields without forecasting the ill effects.
3. Adding/removing features into the forms and reports by removing the existing ones.
4. Assigning new work, which is not in the schedule, due to new modifications in the forms, Basically, he don't have a work schedule.

All of the above changes are made by him by referring to some other products which are very similar to ours.

Basically a normal software development lifecycle will be like this:
 **(A) Analysis** -> **(DS) Design** -> **(DV) Development** -> **(T) Testing** -> **(R) Release**

But we are working as follows:
 **A** -> **DS** -> **DV** -> **DS** -> **T** -> **DS** -> **T** -> **DV** ......... Infinity   --> **R**

This leads to the loss of quality in our project. At the same time, our project is in the danger of getting out of the control. So due to this, once in a meeting we said this to the project manager:

*"Software development and building a house are same. We cannot remove the pillars in the middle of the construction."*

But he did not do anything towards our statement. He is continuing his job in the same way. I don't know if this kind of culture is common in all level of software companies. But this kind of behavior is making us more frustrated and making our employees' efforts useless.

Can anybody tell me how to convince him respectfully? If it is a common behavior, then tell us how to overcome this kind of situation?

Comment: Looks like a prime candidate for Agile development methods. Are any of you guys Scrum certified?

Comment: In my experience it is fairly uncommon for a project manager to have more say than the tech lead of a project. You should be in a more senior position than them surely?

Comment: Hello "An Employee". it sounds like maybe you're asking for ways to convince a project manager to adopt a certain methodology? If so, can you edit your question to reflect that? Also, as @jcmeloni says, if your question is process-oriented, this may fit better on Project Management SE. Just let me know what you want to do as I can move this over if needed. Hope this helps!

Comment: I disagree. The person asking is not a project manager, but is asking how to manage the project manager from below. And I don't think there _are_ whole books that tell employees how to "manage up" in a situation like this.

Comment: Possibly useful: [Managing Up: How to Forge an Effective Relationship With Those Above You](http://www.amazon.com/Managing-Up-Forge-Effective-Relationship/dp/0385507739)

Comment: do you actually mean "unsatisfied" did you mean "unsatisfactory" the title as written does not make sense in the contest of the question

Comment: @Neuromancer - The project manager isn't satisfied with the plan he keeps coming up with -- his own plan. While the asker could mean unsatisfactory, from the context of the question it seems unsatisfied is appropriate. Hope this helps!

Comment: jmort253 sounds like to me that project manger is poorly performing -  a blunter person might say incompetent

Comment: @Neuromancer I have seen this situation more than once in my own experience, so incompetent or not people need to learn how to deal with this kind of manager. You can't fire your manager.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship yes but using "unsatisfied" inverts the meaning of the Question

Comment: This situation is not uncommon for internal development projects. The solution is to simply change YAGNI "You aren't going to need it" to YAGNI (You ARE going to need it). In this case, the ARE is "ease of change". The simplest way to incorporate this is that every time a change occurs and it seems harder than it should, redesign to make it easier to change. At some point, the pieces do start falling into place nicely, assuming you have someone who knows how to make things "easier to change" on the team. This sometimes allows the project complete more quickly because of the better design.

Comment: @Neuromancer I genuinely don't know what you're getting at. The manager is unsatisfied because he keeps changing the plan, and the employee has to figure out how to handle that situation. Not sure where you think there's an inversion--it's clear to everyone else here.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship The Q title as written implies that the developer is not performing - the body of the Q is saying the exact opposite.

Comment: Hm, I guess your experience as a developer is different than mine, because the question read exactly as I expected from reading the heading.

Comment: @Neuromancer Our project manager is Feeling unsatisfied about his new update after being made by us. Meaning He needs more, Not meant that he is unsatisfied with our performances. I guess that he is not making a satisfactory plan before initiating an update in our bigger project. I just asked that 'is this a common behavior with all PM? If not then tell me how to handle when he is making this kind of continuous unplanned updates?'

Comment: @jmort253 As i am a non-native English speaker, I could not able to write the question with cent percent precision. Thanks for updating the same. You can see my above comment for `Neuromancer` to know about the nature of the question. I really did not ask anything about Project management. Again Thanks.

Comment: @CodingKiwi I forgot to tell about the hierarchy of our company. Our project manager is managing the projects as well as he is one of the directors of the company. He is holding some shares too.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yeah. Whenever i get a chance to speak with him, i was actually tried to explain the danger. But he is simply saying that "I am also an ordinary human being. My plans may go wrong sometimes. In order to point/correct mistakes we have appointed you as a Tech. Lead." See, how could i do the assigned tasks with high perfection if i try to point out that mistakes in control flow of the entire project daily.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - Normally the Tech Lead's primary job is to review the work of the team, and handle those tasks beyond the rest of the team.  Most of your duties should revolve around coaching the rest of the team to meet the requirements.

Comment: @Chad since we are a start up, I actually need to participate in developing too. See as a Tech. Lead, basically i have to work on some tougher parts of the project. And sometimes i have to review the other's codes too.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - That sounds like exactly what I said.  So the problem is you do not want to be Tech Lead?

Comment: You as a Tech Lead need Project Management training in concepts and skills.  So does the Project Manager.  The concepts will give you a common language to communicate in, and tools to aid you clarify the issues and deal with them.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship You don;t fire you manager.  You get the organisation to constructively dismiss them from the position right on top of *you*.

Comment: @Hilmar I knew that the very first thing someone is going to do is throw the "agile, scrum" thing at the OP. I think you forget, that from company to company the implementation of "Scrum and Agile" differs a lot. I would say that 70% of the time things like "retrospective, daily stand-up, planning, etc." are just abused and being manipulated by management to force things on to the devs.

Comment: @kiltek: this question is six year old. Things have changed a lot since then.

Comment: I'm baffled that this question does not contain the phrases "scope creep" or even  "requirements." Not once. These are such fundamental concepts for a software team to be aware of.